# Dynamically change text based on URL input

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, parameters

I am using the following code to dynamically change the text on my clients website (www.mydomain.com.au):

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
       var url = window.location.toString();
       var query_string = url.split("?");
               if (query_string[1]) {
       var params = query_string[1].split("&#038;");
       var param_item = params[0].split("=");
       param_item[param_item[0]] = unescape(param_item[1]);
       document.write(param_item["city"]);
               } else {
                       document.write("24 Hour Glass Replacement");
               }
// ]]&gt;</script>
```

It works perfectly fine on the index page. e.g. [www.mydomain.com.au/?city=test](http://www.mydomain.com.au/?city=test)

but when I am using the same code on other pages e.g. http://www.mydomain.com.au/Brisbane.html/?city=test I get a 404 error.

Appreciate any help

Comment: it's totally logic... you only use the QUERY-String, "all which is prefixed by the '?'".
you'll have to check, if there is a query-string and parameter called "city" and if not, use the LAST word after a slash and before the file-suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the / before starting querystring. So, 
try http://www.mydomain.com.au/Brisbane.html?city=test instead of  http://www.mydomain.com.au/Brisbane.html/?city=test

Comment: normally that / would not cause a problem, but that could be why you are getting a 404.

Comment: I would also recommend you use location.search instead of parsing the entire url.

Comment: @MohammadMoezzi please do not forgot to select it as answer and vote if you think my answer is correct and helpful. thanks :)

Comment: @Shahdat unfortunately I do not have a voting power yet but I promise I'll do it when I could. Thanks

Comment: @MohammadMoezzi yes, I see but you can click on the tick to select it as answer of your question. thanks

Comment: @Shahdat is it possible to keep / before the query-string? The very same code is working fine with / here: [link] http://glass.iclix.com.au/brisbane/?city=test

Comment: Okay guys. I figured it out finally. The problem was due to htaccess misconfiguration. I added this bad guy to htaccess and solved the problem:                                                   RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1